# Why Rails returns me `nil` on using associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm trying to call in my ChocolateController:

```
@chocolate.kinds.new(name: "Bitter")
```

where

```
class ChocolateController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @chocolate = Chocolate.new
  end
```

and where I have in my models:

```
class Chocolate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kinds

class Kind < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chocolate
```

I get the next error:

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone please help me, why I get this error? If you need more code, I can provide it. Just ask me about in comments

Comment: what does your `routes.rb` file look like?

Comment: @Mark `resources :chocolates, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :create]`

Comment: I'm assuming you have `belongs_to :chocolate` in your Kind model?

Comment: @henners66 yes! Exactly

Comment: strange - what you have should work, although would be worth trying `@chocolate.kinds << Kind.new(name: bitter)` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @henners66 strange, but it gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method `kinds' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: hmm you did run the migration to create the kinds table right?

Comment: @henners66 yes, I have this table with this field

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this.

```
@chocolate.kinds.build(name: "Bitter")
```

The problem is that `@chocolate.kinds` is nil the `@chocolate` does not have and kinds records so you not getting a `Kind` model back to call new on. Even if it did have `Kinds` records you would be calling new on the collection not on the `Kinds` model.

Comment: but I want to do it in a right way. Not like so. Like how I'm trying

Comment: strange, but now it gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method `kinds' for nil:NilClas`

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII - even if there are no records `@chocolate.kinds` should still be assigned - it is just an array after all that will be empty if there are no Kind objects assigned - something else is going on here that is causing rails not to honour the has_many relationship correctly

Comment: hmmm yea there is something else going on here